# does elastic search use heap memory only for cache?

Tags: elasticsearch, heap-memory, mmap

official elastic search document says, 
elastic search use mmap to map index data into out of jvm heap memory.

Does it mean elastic search manage index data into system virtual memory and jvm heap only use for cache?

if it's true and my elastic search system would not need cache memory.

Would it better less heap size to ensure more memory for index data?